# Java installation isn't working

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, java

I have been trying to install Java and can't get it to work. I was doing what http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/07/31/install-oracle-java-8-9-ubuntu-16-04-linux-mint-18/ said when I came across a problem when doing step 2:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
```

You might want to run `apt-get -f install` to correct these:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
  google-chrome-stable : Depends: libcurl3 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

This is what the terminal said. I'm an absolute noob. I know nothing about how this works.

Comment: Open your terminal with the command `Ctrl + Alt + T` then type: `sudo apt-get install -f`, and your good to go

Answer (score 3):

Please type that command into it:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

When asked for your admin password enter it and note that you won't see any visible feedback as you enter the password. When done press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and sit back and let it do its job. Now go back to that tutorial and continue the other steps as directed.

Kindly see `man apt-get` for a btter understanding of what the `-f` option means:

```
 -f, --fix-broken
       Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages to permit APT
       to deduce a likely solution. If packages are specified, these have to completely correct the problem. The option is sometimes necessary when
       running APT for the first time; APT itself does not allow broken package dependencies to exist on a system. It is possible that a system's
       dependency structure can be so corrupt as to require manual intervention (which usually means using dpkg --remove to eliminate some of the
       offending packages). Use of this option together with -m may produce an error in some situations. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Fix-Broken.
```